# Measuring alcohol when using ginger bug

Tags: final-gravity, ginger-beer, measurements, wild-yeast, lactobacillus

I have recently started to get my feet wet by making some ginger beers using a ginger bug to start the fermentation. 
I would like to know the alcohol content of my final product, but as the ginger bug has both bacteria and yeast eating the sugars I can not figure out how I would measure the final alcohol content!

**3 questions:**

1. Is there a way to figure out how much sugar has been consumed by either the yeast or bacteria, so I can then just use a hydrometer as suggested most places I search?
2. Can I measure the alcohol content by some other indicator besides sugar content?
3. What other tools might be used besides a refractometer or a hydrometer?

Comment: For dry wines, you can use a [Vinometer](https://alcoholcontrols.com/vinometer.html), but I don't know if that will work for your ginger.

Comment: Thanks, but I would very rarely be fermenting out all the sugar as that would not taste nice, so if I understand this tool correctly then it will not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a beginning gravity and an end gravity, it's pretty easy to figure an approximate ABV for your beverage.

The only way to definitively tell how much alcohol is in a solution is to run it through a 
[Ebulliometer](https://www.piwine.com/traditional-ebulliometer-allafrance.html), which is essentially a tiny alcohol still. Sorry, that's the only real ways to do it!

Comment: As your link suggests then an Ebulliometer is not meant for hobby level brewing, it is very expensive. It there something like a hobby level version of this? I am thinking as long as I am within 0.5 ABV of the actual alcohol content it will be good enough for me

Comment: No. There is nothing. Those are your choices. You can send it to a lab for them to tell you how much alcohol and it's fairly cheap.